# Can creep occur at very low stresses?

Tags: material-science

Suppose a metal, say, tin of volume 3mm×3mm×3mm is subject to a very low load of about 15 grams. The metal is kept at zero degree Celsius. Can creep occur AT ALL in the metal?

Is there something like minimum stress and minimum temperature that must be applied to observe creep at all?

Please note that I mentioned a few numerical values just to say how small they are.

Answer (score 0):

Creep relies on diffusional movement of metal atoms through their lattice in response to an external stress. Since that movement is *thermally activated*, the creep mechanism possesses an *activation energy* which must be furnished in order to "turn on" the process.

However, that activation process does not switch on all at once when the thermal energy of each one of the vibrating atoms in the lattice equals the activation energy, because the individual atoms possess a range of energies at any given temperature, and raising that temperature means raising the number of atoms that are above the activation energy threshold.

That distribution yields an exponentially-varying number of activated atoms as the temperature is raised, which means at low temperatures there are so few atoms able to diffuse that the *creep rate* becomes not identically zero but instead *unmeasurably slow*.

This means that at low temperatures, creep is still happening but it would require millenia to produce a creep deflection that was big enough to measure.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, if the minimum activation energy is never provided, can creep still occur? If only a few atoms get enough energy, will the other atoms contribute to creep? Is there a condition when creep is exactly zero?

Comment: creep will not happen at a rate that can be measured if the activation energy is not provided. for *practical* purposes, creep will not happen under those conditions.